# The display layout is faulty in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I am new to Java `JFrame`.

I want the user to insert IP and password, and then click on the `runBtn`.

But after  when running this code, the display is very small:

How can I make the text box bigger and the screen tidier, so the user can insert value and click the button?

```
public class Auditgui extends JFrame{
    private JPanel mainPanel;
    private JPanel textPanel;
    private JPanel consolePanel;
    private JPanel btnPanel;

    private JButton runBtn;

    private JTextField ip;
    private JTextField password;

    private JLabel ipLabel;
    private JLabel passwordLabel;

    private JTextPane textArea1;
    private JScrollPane scroll;

    public Auditgui(){

        mainPanel = new JPanel();
        setContentPane(mainPanel);

        textPanel = new JPanel();

        ipLabel = new JLabel();
        ipLabel.setText("IP");
        passwordLabel = new JLabel();
        passwordLabel.setText("Password");


        ip = new JTextField();
        password = new JTextField();

        textPanel.add(ipLabel);
        textPanel.add(ip);
        textPanel.add(passwordLabel);
        textPanel.add(password);

        consolePanel = new JPanel();
        scroll = new JScrollPane();
        textArea1 = new JTextPane();
        scroll.setViewportView(textArea1);
        consolePanel.add(scroll);

        btnPanel = new JPanel();
        runBtn = new JButton();
        btnPanel.add(runBtn);

        mainPanel.add(textPanel);
        mainPanel.add(consolePanel);
        mainPanel.add(btnPanel);

        textPanel.setSize(400, 300);
        textPanel.setAlignmentX(1);

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Auditgui auditGui = new Auditgui();
        auditGui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        auditGui.setSize(700, 500);
        auditGui.setTitle("Recorder");
        auditGui.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXUJv.png]

Comment: You are currently not using the layout managers of swing correctly. Please have a look through the Swing Tutorial on [Using Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html), which explains the whole topic in detail.

Comment: Also, you didn't give a display text to your `JButton`, use the constructor `new JButton("MyButton")` instead. Additionally, `JTextField` for example also has an appropriate constructor where you can specify the amount of "columns" (one column is equals to the character "w" if I remember correctly) the text field should have: see [`JTextField(int columns)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html#JTextField-int-).

Comment: In addition to the above: 1) `JTextField password` should be `JPasswordField password`. 2) `JTextPane textArea1` should be either `JTextPane textPane1` or `JTextArea textArea1`. Unless formatted text is required, a text area would be simpler, as it can take a number of rows and columns. 3) `auditGui.setSize(..);` should be `auditGui.pack();`

Comment: Also, to simplify your work you might want to consider using a visual designer. If you are using Eclipse have a look at WindowBuilder. Otherwise there are other tools like this for different IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.

When creating a Swing GUI, you work from the inside out.  First, you define the swing components.  Then, you let the [Swing layout managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) size the `JPanels`.  Finally, you pack the `JFrame`.

Here's a GUI I came up with based on the code you posted in your question.

[image: Recorder]

All Swing applications must start with a call to the `SwingUtilities` `invokeLater` method.  This method ensures that the Swing components are created and executed on the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).

A `JFrame` has a default `BorderLayout`.  You should create one or more `JPanels` to place on the `JFrame`.  I created a logon `JPanel` and a text `JPanel`.  You should create each `JPanel` in a separate method or class.  This makes the code easier to understand and makes it easier to rearrange `JPanels` if you decide you want a different `JPanel` layout.

I used a `GridBagLayout` for the logon `JPanel`.  A `GridBagLayout` is useful for creating forms made up of `JLabels` and `JTextFields`.  You should create the Swing components for a `JPanel` in column, row order.  This makes it easier for people to understand your code.

I used a `BorderLayout` for the text `JPanel`.  I have no idea what this text area is used for.  I placed the text area inside of a `JScrollPane` so you can type as much text as you wish.

Here's the complete runnable code.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class AuditGUI implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new AuditGUI());
    }
    
    private JPasswordField passwordField;
    
    private JTextField ipField;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Recorder");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        frame.add(createLogonPanel(), BorderLayout.WEST);
        frame.add(createTextPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    private JPanel createLogonPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 5, 5, 5);
        
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        JLabel label = new JLabel("IP:");
        panel.add(label, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridx++;
        ipField = new JTextField(20);
        panel.add(ipField, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy++;
        label = new JLabel("Password:");
        panel.add(label, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridx++;
        passwordField = new JPasswordField(20);
        panel.add(passwordField, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridwidth = 2;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy++;
        JButton button = new JButton("Login");
        panel.add(button, gbc);
        
        return panel;
    }
    
    private JPanel createTextPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        
        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(5, 40);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        panel.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        return panel;
    }

}
```